# Why is Jquery Version dependent in Bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm developing a UI using bootstrap, so I downloaded it, and studied the Getting started template.  I thought I'd be fancy and update the Jquery versions from 1.11.3 to the newest version 3.10.  I built the dropdown menu and it didn't work.  Replacing 3.10 with 1.11.3 fixes the issue, but I'm curious as to why the version would matter?

Comment: The v3 branch of jQuery has some breaking changes. Until bootstrap removes/amends its reliance on the affected methods you'll have to with v1.9 up to v2.x

Comment: Should I Upgrade to a 2.x version, or does it really matter since it's a CDN fetch?

Comment: You could, although the 2.x versions removed support for legacy browsers, so if your site needs to work in IE8 and lower, stick on v1

Comment: I'd stick with what is in the getting started template. Have a read of http://semver.org/ for an explanation of semantic versioning.

Comment: @Steve Nice read...I went ahead and upgraded to the last version in the 1.x branch to ensure backward browser compatibility, 1.12.4